# Ejecutar código cada n segundos con kotlin

Tags: android, android-studio

Intento encontrar la forma de ejecutar una función cada n segundos, para cambiar un texto por ejemplo.
Existen muchas tutoriales pero casi todos están en java, o están muy desactualizado y ahora no funcionan.

Puede encontrar esto pero al parecer es para que se ejecute lo que esta dentro, después del tiempo indicado. Lo que deseo es que se ejecute cada cierto tiempo, como un bucle y no solo una vez.

```
fun refreshtext(){
        Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed({
            
            actuazlizartexto() 

        }, 3000)
    }
```

**Editado**
Ahora estoy comprobando si existe conexión ha internet. si tiene no pasa nada pero si no tiene, muestro un texto.

Quisiera que cuando la conexión regrese se oculte el texto, por ello pensé que puedo ejecutar el código por ejemplo cada 5 segundos, hasta que la conexión se restablezca, y en ese momento detener la ejecución de ese código .
Esa es una de las implementación que deseo agregar, tengo otras en las que necesito hacer algo similar, por ello saber como puedo solucionar esta ya me ayudaría bastante con las demás

Así esta mi código:
Al parecer no existe un método para comprobar la conexión como setOnClickListener, por ejemplo que detecta automáticamente un clic, por ello deseo realizarlo de la forma como explique.

```
val cm = getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager
val activeNetwork: NetworkInfo? = cm.activeNetworkInfo
val isConnected: Boolean = activeNetwork?.isConnectedOrConnecting == true

if (!isConnected){
        screen.visibility = View.VISIBLE  //MUESTRA UN TEXTO QUE DICE SIN CONEXION
        }
```

Comment: Hay varias formas. Si das mas contexto sobre lo que intentas hacer puedo decirte cuales son las mas apropiadas. Pienso que lo que estás buscando es un observable.

Answer (score 3):

> Al parecer no existe un método para comprobar la conexión

Claro que si existe, se llama [registerNetworkCallback](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/net/ConnectivityManager#registernetworkcallback)

Puedes crear un archivo aparate para esto y de esa forma compartirlo con otras partes de tu app. Este es un ejemplo básico usando los `StateFlow` de kotlin:

```
object NetworkConnection {
    val isConnected = MutableStateFlow(false)

    fun initialize(context: Context) {
        val cm = context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager
        val request = NetworkRequest.Builder().build()
        val callback = object : ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback() {
            override fun onAvailable(network: android.net.Network) {
                isConnected.value = true
            }

            override fun onLost(network: android.net.Network) {
                isConnected.value = false
            }
        }
        cm.registerNetworkCallback(request, callback)
    }

}
```

Para usarlo primero debes inicializarlo, por ejemplo al crear tu mainActivity: `NetworkConnection.initialize(this)`

Luego lo observas así:

```
lifecycleScope.launchWhenStarted {
    NetworkConnection.isConnected.collect { isConnected ->
        screen.isVisible = !isConnected
    }
}
```

o así:

```
NetworkConnection.isConnected
    .onEach { screen.isVisible = !it }
    .launchIn(lifecycleScope)
```

El StateFlow también te permite obtener un resultado síncrono cuando lo necesites. Para ello debes acceder a la propiedad value: `NetworkConnection.isConnected.value`

Si sólo necesitas comprobar la conexión en un uníco lugar de tu app, entonces puedes usar el callback directamente:

```
val cm = getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager
val request = NetworkRequest.Builder().build()
val callback = object : ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback() {
    override fun onAvailable(network: android.net.Network) {
        screen.isVisible = false
    }
    override fun onLost(network: android.net.Network) {
        screen.isVisible = true
    }
}
cm.registerNetworkCallback(request, callback)
```

Comment: Pensaba que no existía un Callback, me parecía raro, simplificara mucho las cosas, gracias

Answer (score 1):

Para ejecutar código cada n segundos con kotlin, puedes hacer uso de un Handler, y definir la cantidad de millisegundos en las cuales deseas se ejecute el proceso

```
val myHandler = Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())

myHandler.post(object : Runnable {
    override fun run() {
        /*-----*/
        //ejecuta proceso...
        /*-----*/
        myHandler.postDelayed(this, 5000 /*5 segundos*/)
    }
})
```

Para comprobar la conexiòn puedes usar el mètodo.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51141970/check-internet-connectivity-android-in-kotlin/57237708#57237708

```
fun isOnline(context: Context): Boolean {
    val connectivityManager =
        context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager
    if (connectivityManager != null) {
        val capabilities =
            connectivityManager.getNetworkCapabilities(connectivityManager.activeNetwork)
        if (capabilities != null) {
            if (capabilities.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR)) {
                Log.i("Internet", "NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR")
                return true
            } else if (capabilities.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI)) {
                Log.i("Internet", "NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI")
                return true
            } else if (capabilities.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_ETHERNET)) {
                Log.i("Internet", "NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_ETHERNET")
                return true
            }
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

---

**Como detener un handler.postDelayed()**

para detener un handler.postDelayed() puedes usar:

```
myHandler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null)
```

ejemplo:

```
   lateinit var myHandler : Handler

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)


        myHandler = Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())

        myHandler.post(object : Runnable {
            override fun run() {
                /*-----*/
                playSound()
                /*-----*/
                val postDelayed: Any = myHandler.postDelayed(this, 5000 /*5 segundos*/)
            }
        })


        val btn_click_me = findViewById(R.id.button) as Button
        btn_click_me.setOnClickListener {
            //Detiene handler.
            myHandler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null)
        }

    }
```

Comment: Hola gracias, funciona como lo esperaba, como puedo detener el  Handler

Comment: @Redox yo te recomendaría usar kotlin coroutines en vez de un handler. Son mas kotlin idiomatic y fáciles de controlar

Comment: Gracias por la recomendación, voy a leer la documentación si necesito ayuda elaborare una pregunta.

Comment: @Redox agregue como detener el handler, usa handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null) , saludos.