# Cambiar de Activity desde una Corrutina

Tags: android, android-studio

Uso la siguiente [implementación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/429816/ejecutar-c%C3%B3digo-cada-n-segundos-con-kotlin) para detectar si hay conexión a internet, funciona bien.
Ahora necesito que cuando no se disponga de conexión se lance una Activity, pero esto me genera un error. Se que dentro de las corrutinas, no se puede cambiar la interfaz de usuario, sin embargo no logro entender por que no se puede cambiar de activity desde ellas.

**MainActivity**

```
lifecycleScope.launchWhenStarted {
            NetworkConnection.isConnected.collect { isConnected ->

                if (isConnected){
                    ...
                }else{
                    val intent_permiso = Intent(this, PermisoActivity::class.java)
                    startActivity(intent_permiso)
                }
               
            }
        }
```

**Error**

```
None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied: 
public constructor Intent(p0: Context!, p1: Class<*>!) defined in android.content.Intent
public constructor Intent(p0: String!, p1: Uri!) defined in android.content.Intent
```

Comment: otra vez? Tus preguntas suelen ser sobre errores causados porque una función te pide un Context y le pasas otra cosa. Por qué no revisas que no sea el mismo caso?

Answer (score 0):

Así lo resolví

```
val intent_permiso = Intent(this@MainActivity, PermisoActivity::class.java)
startActivity(intent_permiso)
```

[Aquí lo encontre](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/this-expressions.html#qualified-this)

> Para acceder this desde un alcance externo (una clase , función de
> extensión o literal de función etiquetada con receptor ), escriba
> this@label, donde se supone que @label es una etiqueta en el alcance
> this: